# Conkeror: change default download directory

Tags: download, conkeror

By default conkeror saves files in my home directory. I want it to save it in `~/dl` instead without asking. http://conkeror.org/Tips#Downloads wasn't helpful. I suppose the solution should be a javascript code in `~/.conkerorrc`, because there is no variable for default download location.

I'm on Debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this in my RC file:

```
cwd = get_home_directory();
cwd.append("Downloads");
```